# How strong (if any) is the correlation in this graph (prt sc from a lecture slide)

Tags: correlation

In this graph, how strong (if any) is the correlation? The image is from a presentation of another speaker (source: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLiVD.jpg).

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WLiVD.jpg]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer this question we need to extract numbers with some plot digitizer and then compute correlation coefficient. I've used Engauge Digitizer and get answer r=-0.43. Such value is treated as moderate correlation in social sciences and as low correlation in nature sciences.

Comment: Digitizer looks like an interesting tool, thanks for pointer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought there might also be a method of calculating the angle of the line (given both ends, as of course the scales are not to scale).
Isn't -0.43 treated as weak even in social sciences? E.g. Dancey and Reidy (2004) and also Salkin categorise as follows:
0.9 - 1  Very strong
0.7 - 0.89  Strong 
0.5 - 0.69   Moderate
Isn't it also that a correlation of .7 explains only 50% of your data, and so on (I read somewhere that the correlation coefficient squared times 100 yields the percentage of data explained by the hypothesis)?

Comment: @Mike The angle of the line has meaning *provided the aspect ratio is 1:1.* Specifically, the two scales have to be stretched so that one standard deviation on each has the same length. When any scatterplot is redrawn in this way, with a little practice one can estimate the correlation by eye reasonably well (reliably distinguishing absolute correlations of 0, .3, .5, .7, and .9). This is a basic skill; for resources in learning it, please visit https://www.causeweb.org/cwis/SPT--BrowseResources.php?ParentId=41.

Comment: @Mike The strength of correlation score is rather the matter of personal taste. You may see also this tables http://www.strath.ac.uk/aer/materials/4dataanalysisineducationalresearch/unit4/correlationsdirectionandstrength/